# EF select from same table twice

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, join

I have table

```
Task
  task_id int
  name varchar
```

and table

```
  Event
      event_id int autoincrement
      time timestamp
      task_id int
```

one task have many events (created, pending, executed, completed and so on)

I wanted to show, in one query, both tasks and it's LAST event. I came up with following statement:

```
var q = context.Event
      .Include(x => x.Task)
      .Where(e => e.EventId == e.Task.Event.Max(e1 => e1.EventId))
      .Select(x => new
      {
         x.Task.Name
         x.EventId,
         x.Time,
      });
```

which render to SQL:

```
  SELECT t.name, e.event_id, e.time
      FROM event AS e
      INNER JOIN task AS t ON e.task_id = t.task_id
      WHERE e.event_id = (
          SELECT MAX(e0.event_id)
          FROM task.event AS e0
          WHERE t.task_id = e0.task_id)
```

Great, but now I wonder if it possible to do the same for FIRST event in task as well. So I need to join same table twice and stuck

I need EF C# clause for following SQL:

```
SELECT t.name, e1.event_id, e1.ts, e2.event_id, e2.ts
FROM event e1, event e2, task t
 WHERE t.task_id = e1.task_id
 AND e1.task_id = e2.task_id
 AND e1.event_id = (
          SELECT MIN(event_id)
          FROM event
          WHERE task_id = t.task_id)
 AND e2.event_id = (
          SELECT MAX(event_id)
          FROM event
          WHERE task_id = t.task_id)
```

Please help

Comment: Take a look at the 'let' keyword, it might help you with this clause
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve data about each task with their first and last events, it would help that Task has a navigation property set up for it's associated events. Then you can employ something like:

```
var q = context.Task
  .Select(t => new
  {
     t.Name
     FirstEvent = x.Events
         .OrderBy(e => e.Time)
         .Select(e => new { e.EventId, e.Time })
         .FirstOrDefault()
     LastEvent = x.Events
         .OrderByDescending(e => e.Time)
         .Select(e => new { e.EventId, e.Time })
         .FirstOrDefault()
  });
```